# openvpn 's netmask and client-to-client mode

Tags: openvpn

I had set openvpn 's config as

```
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
client-to-client
```

and set ccd/username as

```
iroute 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

BUT, the client's netmask was 255.255.255.252 yet. and server's ifconfig is:

```
tun0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
        inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
        UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I want to set client and server 's mask as 255.255.255.0, for client-to-client communication.

Comment: Coud you post the actual routing tables from server + client?

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN (in layer 3/tun mode) creates virtual point-to-point (like you would get with RS232 for example) links between the server and each client. Any traffic between clients goes trough the server (if there is no client-to-client directive, the server just drops those packets).

Check the routing tables of the clients they should say:

10.8.0.0/24 interface tun0

If you use OpenVPN in layer2/tap mode then it creates a virtual ethernet card with the proper IP and netmask.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is all a matter of setting the `topology` parameter to `subnet`, and then specifying the netmask on the server parameter at the server's **config file**, like:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

Without the `topology` parameter it seems those changes will not work.

Extracted from [here](https://superuser.com/a/933943/268923).